# How to create a "back" button to an edit form for AngularJS Datatables using a form directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a grid using AngularJS Datatables and added two more buttons "edit" and "delete" in the last column.

How does the grid/table is rendered?

**HTML**

```
<!-- Required CSS and JS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.6.0/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<!-- AnglarJS, AngularJS Datatables and related plugins -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.6.0/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.6.0/plugins/bootstrap/angular-datatables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.6.0/plugins/buttons/angular-datatables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.6.0/plugins/columnfilter/angular-datatables.columnfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<!-- Table/grid -->
<table datatable dt-options="concessoes.standardOptions" dt-columns="concessoes.standardColumns" dt-instance="concessoes.dtInstance" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-hide="phone">ID</th>
            <th data-class="expand"> Processo</th>
            <th data-class="expand"> Objeto</th>
            <th data-hide="phone"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> UF</th>
            <th>Região</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet"> Macrossegmento</th>
            <th data-hide="expand"> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**JavaScript/ "ConcessoesCtrl"**

```
var vm = this;
vm.dtInstance = {};
vm.standardOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
    // This is from where the data is coming
    .fromSource('/api/BasesDados/Concessoes/concessoes.php')
    .withOption('scrollX', '100%')
    .withDOM("<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'l>r>" +
            "t" +
            "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>")
    .withBootstrap()
    .withButtons([
        {extend: 'colvis', text: 'Vizualização'},
        {extend: 'copy', text: 'Copiar'},
        {extend: 'print', text: 'Imprimir'},
        {extend: 'excel', text: 'MS Excel'},
        {
            text: 'Incluir projeto',
            key: '1',
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                // This is the function to add a project
                $scope.adicionarProjeto();
            }
        }
    ]);

// Conlunas que serão mostradas
vm.standardColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').notVisible(),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('processo'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('objeto'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('uf'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('regiao'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('macro'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Ações').notSortable().renderWith(botoesDeAcao)
];
// Action buttons: edit and delete buttons
function botoesDeAcao(data, type, full, meta) {
    vm.projeto[data.id] = data;
    return '<button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="editarProjeto(' + data.id + ')">' +
        '   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>' +
        '</button>&nbsp;' +
        '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="excluirProjeto(' + data.id + ')">' +
        '   <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>' +
        '</button>';
}
// This is the function to edit the data
$scope.editarProjeto = function (projetoId) {
    // It calls a directive which renders the edititng form 
    var formularioDeEdicao = $compile("<div formulario-do-projeto></div>")($scope);
    $("article#render-form").html(formularioDeEdicao);
    // TODO: Editar os dados, chamar o servidor para fazer as alterações, então, dar um refresh na tabela
    vm.dtInstance.reloadData();
};
```

How does the grid look like?

[image]

When I click the edit button (in blue) a directive is called and then a form for editing the data is opened.

**HTML Template**

```
<form id="order-form" class="smart-form" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <header>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
            <i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-left'></i>
        </button>
        <b class="text-warning">Concessão & PPPs</b>
    </header>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Projeto</strong></legend>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-circle"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="NomeDoPrograma" placeholder="Nome do programa" ng-model="NomeDoPrograma">
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-bars"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="NomeDoProcesso" placeholder="Nome do processo" ng-model="NomeDoProcesso">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-bullseye"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="Objeto" placeholder="Objeto" ng-model="Objeto">
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-usd"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="InvestimentoEstimado" placeholder="Investimento estimado" ng-model="InvestimentoEstimado">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-tree"></i>
                    <select type="text" name="Natureza" placeholder="Natureza" ng-model="Natureza">
                        <option value="">Natureza</option>
                        <option value="Concessão">Concessão</option>
                        <option value="PMI">PMI</option>
                        <option value="PPP">PPP</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                    <select type="text" name="Esfera" placeholder="Esfera" ng-model="Esfera">
                        <option value="">Esfera</option>
                        <option valur="Estadual">Estadual</option>
                        <option value="Federal">Federal</option>
                        <option value="Municipal">Municipal</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                    <select name="Uf" ng-model="Uf">
                        <option value="">Estado</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="estado in estados" value="{{estado}}">{{estado}}<option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-map-o"></i>
                    <select name="Regiao" placeholder="Região" ng-model="Regiao">
                        <option value="">Região</option>
                        <option value="Centro-oeste">Centro-oeste</option>
                        <option value="Nordeste">Nordeste</option>
                        <option value="Norte">Norte</option>
                        <option value="Sudeste">Sudeste</option>
                        <option value="Sul">Sul</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-industry"></i>
                    <select name="Macrossegmento" placeholder="Macrossegmento" ng-model="Macrossegmento">
                        <option value="">Macrossegmento</option>
                        <option value="Saneamento básico">Saneamento básico</option>
                        <option value="Infraestrutura urbana">Infraestrutura urbana</option>
                        <option value="Energia">Energia</option>
                        <option value="Multissetorial">Multissetorial</option>
                        <option value="Mobilidade urbana">Mobilidade urbana</option>
                        <option value="Logística">Logística</option>
                        <option value="Construção naval">Construção naval</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-life-ring"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="Modalidade" placeholder="Modalidade" ng-model="Modalidade">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Edital & licitação</strong></legend>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-trophy"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="VencedorDaLicitacao" placeholder="Vencedor da licitação" ng-model="VencedorDaLicitacao">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="PrevisaoDoEdital" placeholder="Previsão do edital" ng-model="PrevisaoDoEdital">
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar-minus-o"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="PublicacaoDoEdital" placeholder="Publicação do edital" ng-model="PublicacaoDoEdital">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Controle</strong></legend>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-link"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="LinkDoProcesso" placeholder="Link do processo" ng-model="LinkDoProcesso">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-compass"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="FonteDaConsulta" placeholder="Fonte da consulta" ng-model="FonteDaConsulta">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user-circle"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="Validador" placeholder="Validador" ng-model="Validador">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-list-ul"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="SituacaoDoProcesso" placeholder="Situação do processo" ng-model="SituacaoDoProcesso">
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-certificate"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="StatusDaOperacao" placeholder="Status da operação" ng-model="StatusDaOperacao">
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <section>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Validacao" ng-model="Validacao">
                <i></i>Validar as informações acima</label>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Anexos</strong></legend>
        <section>
            <div class="input input-file">
                <span class="button">
                    <input type="file" name="Arquivo" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value" ng-model="Arquivo">Procurar arquivos
                </span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Incluir arquivos" readonly="">
            </div>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <strong>Histórico</strong>
        </legend>
        <section>
            <label class="textarea"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-history"></i>
                <textarea rows="5" name="Observacoes" placeholder="Observações sobre o projeto e outras informaçoes importantes" ng-model="Observacoes"></textarea>
            </label>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
    <footer>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
            Excluir projeto <i class='fa fa-trash'></i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            Cancelar <i class='fa fa-times'></i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            Salvar & Voltar <i class='fa fa-save'></i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="salvarProjeto()">
            Salvar <i class="fa fa-send-o"></i>
        </button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

**JavaScript/ "formularioDoProjeto"**

```
.directive('formularioDoProjeto', ['FormData', function (FormData) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        templateUrl: "app/database/concessoes/formulario-do-projeto.html"
    };
}])
```

My doubt is **how do I create a button to go back to the grid after aditing tha data from a directive that is rendered in the same page as the grid?**

How does the form directive looks like?

[image]

When I click the edit button the function ***editarProjeto()*** is called and it renders the directive to the DOM using the ***.html()*** method:

```
$scope.editarProjeto = function (projetoId) {
    var formularioDeInclusao = $compile("<div formulario-do-projeto></div>")($scope);
    $("article#render-form").html(formularioDeInclusao);
    //vm.dtInstance.reloadData();
};
```

**Now, what is the approach to add a "back to the grid" button in the form such that the grid keeps its latest state** (when the user uses a filter and calls the edit form, she/he will find the form the same way it was left before calling the edit form when she/he presses the "back" button**?**

Sorry for any mistake when asking the question. If you downvote this question, please, let me know why, so I can correct the issues.

Comment: Where is the `$("article#render-form")` in your HTML? Does clicking "Edit" bring you to a new URL? or is it a pop-up or modal form?

Comment: `.html` is replacing the current page content so technically you can't go back to the exact state. You might want to navigate to a NEW EDIT PAGE and load the details, so you have a state to go back to.. Might need to setup [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld)

Comment: @Brian Glaz I'm sorry! The element you are referring to is the parent of the table. So, .HTML is replacing the table by a form as @ Searching said. I'm using ui-router already.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I found a solution based on the brainstorming you gave me. Look, I just added the directive directly into the page, created a `$scope.editing` variable initially set to false, used `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to show the table and hide the form and then used the buttons to toggle the `$scope.editing` variable. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

HTML

```
<table ng-show="!editing">...</table>

<project-form ng-hide="!editing"></project-form>
```

JavaScript

```
.controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope){
    // It starts as false so the grid/table is shown first
    $scope.editing = false;
    $scope.backToGrid = function(){
        $scope.editing = false;
    };

    // When I want to edit the project I set the $scope.editing to true, so the form is shown
    $scope.editProject = function(projectId){
        $scope.editing = true;
        // The rest of the steps goes here

    };
});
```